# Extracting .zip filenames from given URL using regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to extract the .zip filenames from given URl. Here is my code-

```py
import re

print(re.findall(r'href=[\'"]?([^\'" >]+)','<a href="http://www.example.com/files/world_data1.zip"><b>World Data Part 1</b></a> <br/> <a href="http://www.example.com/files/world_data2.zip"><b>World Data Part 2</b></a>'))
```

For example:

Input -`<a href="http://www.example.com/files/world_data1.zip"><b>World Data Part 1</b></a> <br/> <a href="http://www.example.com/files/world_data2.zip"><b>World Data Part 2</b></a>`

Expected Output - `world_data1.zip,world_data2.zip`.

I tried using .zip $ in various format but I get an empty list. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Why are you parsing HTML with regex to begin with? Couldn't you use something like [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)?

Comment: [This may be of some help to you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: I did know we can use BeautifulSoup library. But I am trying to solve it with regex approach. Thanks for the input by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
import re

html = """'&nbsp;<a href="http://www.example.com/files/world_data1.zip"><b>World Data Part 1</b></a> <br/> <a href="http://www.example.com/files/world_data2.zip"><b>World Data Part 2</b></a>'"""

rx = re.compile(r"""href=(["'])(.*?)\1""")
links = [filename 
    for m in rx.finditer(html) 
    for filename in [m.group(2).split('/')[-1]]
    if filename.endswith('.zip')]
print(links)
```

Yielding

```
['world_data1.zip', 'world_data2.zip']
```

---

The idea is to get the `href` attributes first, split by `/` and check if the last part ends with `.zip`.
However, consider using a parser like `BeautifulSoup` and some `xpath` queries instead.
See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/wYgSXX/1) for the expression.

Comment: Interesting. I have never used this finditer but I will try using this. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import re

s = '&nbsp;<a href="http://www.example.com/files/world_data1.zip"><b>World Data Part 1</b></a> <br/> <a href="http://www.example.com/files/world_data2.zip"><b>World Data Part 2</b></a>'

print(re.findall(r'href="[^"]+?/([^/"]+\.zip)"', s))
```

Or, for more rigorously, use the following way:

```
import os

from pyquery import PyQuery as pq

doc = pq(s)
a_list = doc('a[href]')  # Get all `a` elements that have a `href` attrib.
hrefs = [os.path.basename(a.attrib['href']) for a in a_list]
print(list(filter(lambda x: x.endswith('.zip'), hrefs)))
```

Comment: I have tried the second approach you mentioned. Thanks for the help. Appreciate it!